# Swiftで異なるStoryboard間の画面遷移について

Tags: swift

Swiftの以下のようなコードで、異なるStoryboard間の画面遷移を実装できました。

```
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TestViewController", bundle: nil)
    let next: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

しかし、このコードだと、下側からニョキっと画面が覆いかぶさるだけで、画面を下方向にスワイプさせると画面が前のページに戻ってしまいます。
新しいStoryboard側だけを表示して、画面を前ページに戻れないようにするにはどうしたら良いですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

その挙動は現在のiOSのデフォルトで、異なるStoryboard間であろうと、同一Storyboard内であろうと発生するものです。

遷移先のView ControllerのAttribute inspectorを開いて、「Presentation」の設定を確認して下さい。おそらく「Automatic」(もしかしたら、「Page Sheet」)になっているのだと思われます。それを「Full Screen」に変更してみて下さい。

Storyboard上での設定が分かりにくい場合には、コードで変更することもできます。

```
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TestViewController", bundle: nil)
        let next: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        next.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //<-
        self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。PresentationがAutomaticになっていました。コードと両方試してみました。無事できました！

Comment: @gncc さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。お役に立てたのであれば幸いです。昔のiOSでは見られなかった挙動なので、私も最初は「なんでやねん？」と固まってしまいましたが、ネット上(確か英語版のstackoverflow)で解決策を見つけることができたので、比較的早く解決できました。gncc さんもご自身の経験が活かせそうな質問を見つけられましたら、ぜひ回答を書いてみて下さい。